# Extracting data frame based on matching IDs

Tags: r

I have a data frame (BD) with over 3000 subjects from which I want to extract only a specific number of subjects based on their IDs. I have the IDs saved as a data frame (IDs).
If I try this code:

```
df <- BD %>%
  filter(EID == as.list(IDs))
```

The code works/has no error message, but the df I get has 0 observations. And all IDs from 'IDs' MUST be there.

Comment: Try `BD %>% filter(EID %in% IDs$id)`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the below

```
df<-
  ID %>% filter(EID %in% (IDs$list_you_have))
```

?